# The smallest cardinality of a set such that it is transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I am currently stuck on a set theory problem. Suppose we have set S = $ \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$ and set A $\subseteq S * S$ given by $A = \{ (1, 1), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 2) \} $.

Now, suppose $B \subseteq S * S$ and is a transitive relation such that $A \subseteq B$. **What is the smallest cardinality of $B$?**

My working was as follows:
For $B$ to be transitive, for every $(a, b) \in B$ and $(b, c) \in B$ there must be $(a, c) \in B$.

As $A \subseteq B$, we can get the smallest set if we consider the elements in $A$ which already hold a transitive relation and simply add any 'missing' elements to fulfil the remaining elements that lack this relation.

There's an issue though. Once we add those 'missing' elements, they become part of the set and so need to hold the transitive relation for themselves. For example, we have from $A$, $(1,4)$ and $(4,3)$. Therefore we need to add $(1, 3)$ to complete the transitive relation between those two. However, this creates another issue - $(1, 3)$ (the added 'missing' element) and $(3, 5)$ (from set $A$) do not satisfy the transitive relation (i.e. there is a missing $(1, 5)$).

Once I got this impression, it made me believe that manually determining all the pairs to add to $B$ in order to satisfy the transitive requirement for the set may take a while.

The given solution says the answer is '25' (i.e. the entirety of the elements of $S * S$). Is this verifiable without manually crunching all the pairs required to satisfy the requirement? If so, it would be funny that the 'smallest' possible cardinality is the entire set.

Comment: BIG HINT: Notice that among the members of $A$ are these ordered pairs: $(1,4)$, $(4,3)$, $(3,5)$,$(5,2)$, and $(2,1)$.

Comment: Warshall's algorithm (look it up!) is a very efficient algorithm for find the transitive closure of a relation. Well, very efficient for a computer, maybe not so efficient for calculations by hand on large examples, but still good to know about it.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I'm still a bit stuck. Does this mean we need to add (1,3) (4,5) (3,2) and (2,1) to complete those pairs?

Comment: Look at the pattern resulting from the particular pairs I highlighted and the order in which I listed them.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I apologise for being slow, I still cannot configure the significance of the pattern. I have my final exam today for this topic so perhaps after I'll mull on it and get back to you :))

Comment: Think of a circle with the numbers $1,4,3,5,2$ on the circumference, in that order, with an arrow pointing from each to the next one along. Then consider that given any two of the five numbers you can follow the arrows to get from the one to the other. Clear now?

Comment: I say, CLEAR NOW?

Comment: So does this mean that we don't actually have to add (1,3) etc because the circular pattern accounts for them?

Answer (score 0):

The question was basically solved in the comments by  [Paul Tanenbaum](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10239179) and [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10240966)

It is enough to notice that there is a cycle going through all elements of $S$, namely $1\to 4\to 3\to 5\to 2\to 1$.

Using the arrows in this cycle one can get from any of the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ to all remaining numbers.